# Why is the tab icon hidden in my Android application?

Tags: java, android

Why is the tab icon hidden as shown in the picture?

[image: http://i43.tinypic.com/mcyecl.jpg]

Comment: provide your layout xml code atleast...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it's hidden, it looks like your icon is overlaying the tab text, correct?

Your image is not the right dimensions. please take a look at this link,

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_tab.html

For all you need to know about tab icons.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to set view instead of just icon. Can not put exact syntax at the moment. Use `getTab().setView(your_view)` instead of `getTab().setIcon(r.id.your_icon)`.

What's going actually is that all layout properties are default, except image bitmap. So it  might behave unexpectedly.